# Why is event.currentTarget returning null sometimes?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom-events, mouseclick-event

I have three svg icon components nested in buttons. Each of these buttons has an onClick handler that simply passes the button's name attribute to a function.

However, sometimes `event.currentTarget` returns null, and I can't figure out why. When `currentTarget` **works**, the `console.log` output in `changeModeHandler` shows the button tag as empty. See the first log in the picture below. When it **doesn't** work, it logs the `currentTarget` with both the button and svg icon child. But in both cases, `event.currentTarget.name` prints the correct button name, even though currentTarget returns null one line later.

How can I reliably access the name attribute on the parent button element through the event object?

**FOUND A FIX, BUT I DONT KNOW WHY IT WORKS**

In changeModeHandler, if I store currentTarget.name in a constant it works, but I have no idea why. If someone could enlighten me I would greatly appreciate it.

```js
// storing currentTarget.name in a const solves the problem
  function changeModeHandler(event) {
    const name = event.currentTarget.name;
    console.log(event.currentTarget, event.currentTarget.name);
    raiseState(() => name);
  }
```

[image]

```js
  function changeModeHandler(event) {
    console.log(event.currentTarget, event.currentTarget.name);
    raiseState(() => event.currentTarget.name);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={changeModeHandler}
        className=""
        type="button"
        name="explain"
      >
        <BookOpenIcon className="mode-icon" />
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={changeModeHandler}
        className=""
        type="button"
        name="summary"
      >
        <KeyIcon className="mode-icon" />
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={changeModeHandler}
        className=""
        type="button"
        name="example"
      >
        <ListBulletIcon className="mode-icon" />
      </button>
    </>
```

Comment: happening because of the Icon u are using inside the button, I ran the code it should work and works

Comment: "*When it doesn't work, it logs the currentTarget*" no, when it doesn't work, you get no log at all, because `event.currentTarget.name` in the call `console.log(event.currentTarget, event.currentTarget.name);` throws an error, so it does not get to logging anything.

Comment: @SamiUllah Yes, it works without the icons. I need the icons however.

Comment: Figuring out exactly what the console is doing can be pretty confusing. There's the issue of event bubbling, the fact that your component may be re-rendering, and I've even seen the console mis-report the run time value of object properties. I left a suggestion for a simpler approach below.

Answer (score 0):

You could just pass the data you need (the name) to the handler ahead of time, then you don't need to worry about exactly what's going on with the event.

```
  const changeModeHandler = (buttonName) => (event) => {
    raiseState(() => buttonName);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={changeModeHandler('explain')}
        className=""
        type="button"
        name="explain"
      >
        <BookOpenIcon className="mode-icon" />
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={changeModeHandler('summary')}
        className=""
        type="button"
        name="summary"
      >
        <KeyIcon className="mode-icon" />
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={changeModeHandler('example')}
        className=""
        type="button"
        name="example"
      >
        <ListBulletIcon className="mode-icon" />
      </button>
    </>
  );
```